# Perl script to convert unix month to number

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a quick script or time/date module to convert the below Unix format

```
[randy@go1server03 /ftp/device]$ date.

Thu Apr 24 13:48:28 UTC 2014
```

to something like only `04-24` , where 04 is month April and 24 is the date. Is their any quick and dirty way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to convert a date from `Thu Apr 24 13:48:28 UTC 2014` to `04-24`, or are you trying to output the current date as `04-24`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If one of the below answers ends up being your final solution, please give them a checkmark to close out the question. If others are useful, consider giving them both up votes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $date = localtime->strftime('%m-%d');
print $date;
```

***DEMO***: http://ideone.com/K1hVy8

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want perl? Try;

```
date +%m-%d
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the core module [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) for date manipulation in Perl.

Here's a one-liner (using the current time):

```
perl -MTime::Piece -wE '$t = Time::Piece->new; say $t->strftime( q{%m-%d} );'
```

Or to do this in a script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->new;
say $t->strftime('%m-%d');
```

Comment: `perl -MPOSIX -E'say strftime "%m-%d", localtime'`

Comment: That works as well. I don't know why I bothered including a one-liner, there are obviously shorter ways to achieve the same thing. I don't use `Time::Piece` for brevity, though.

Comment: Who said anything about brevity? I *HATE* Time::Piece because it's so damn hard to know if code using it correct or not. It tries to make incorrect-looking code work correctly (e.g. `$d += ONE_DAY`;), so you always left wondering if you got the right result or not. As long as you don't use it to do date calculations, no problem, tough :)

Comment: use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $date = strftime("%m-%d", localtime(time));
print $date;     This is what i used and it worked . thanks everyone

Comment: `perl -MTime::Piece -E ”say localtime->strftime('%m-%d')”`

Comment: @ikegami I do indeed use it for calculations, although I try to avoid the magic constants. There were some nasty bugs related to date math in an earlier release, but those have been fixed. Could you elaborate on what you don't like about it? I see `Time::Piece` tossed around so much on SO, it would be nice to know about limitations.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->now->format_cldr("MM-dd")'
```